# Adding a new column or row as pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add one Column and one Row by using a `pd.Series` object. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Title": "Titanic",    "ReleaseYear": 1997, "Director": "James Cameron"},
    {"Title": "Spider-Man", "ReleaseYear": 2002, "Director": "Sam Raimi"}
])

# Add a new row
new_movie_row = pd.Series(['Jurassic Park', 1993, 'Steven Spielberg'])
df.loc[2] = new_row

# Add a new column
new_keyword_column = pd.Series(['Boat', 'Spider', 'Dinosaur'])
df['Keyword'] = new_keyword_column
df
```

This seems to add the Column fine, however the Row gives me all `NaN`:

[image]

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas tries to align based on index/column names this is called [`Data Alignment`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html?highlight=alignment#intro-to-data-structures), we can use `.tolist` here.

```
df.loc[2] = new_movie_row.tolist()
df
           Title  ReleaseYear          Director
0        Titanic         1997     James Cameron
1     Spider-Man         2002         Sam Raimi
2  Jurassic Park         1993  Steven Spielberg
```

This applies same for adding columns too

```
new_keyword_column = pd.Series(['Boat', 'Spider', 'Dinosaur'],index=[4,5,6])  # Notice the Index is 4, 5, 6.

df['new'] = new_keyword_column
df
           Title  ReleaseYear          Director  new
0        Titanic         1997     James Cameron  NaN
1     Spider-Man         2002         Sam Raimi  NaN
2  Jurassic Park         1993  Steven Spielberg  NaN
```

Since indexes don't align you get all `NaN`, to counter that you can use `.tolist()`

```
df['new'] = new_keyword_column.tolist()
df
           Title  ReleaseYear          Director       new
0        Titanic         1997     James Cameron      Boat
1     Spider-Man         2002         Sam Raimi    Spider
2  Jurassic Park         1993  Steven Spielberg  Dinosaur
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain how using `tolist()` solves the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- how does Pandas try to align the row by default though? With three values and three columns, I'm surprised Pandas doesn't 'auto-align' that on its own?

Comment: Did not get you can you, please elaborate? You can read more details about [`Data alignment` here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html?highlight=alignment#data-alignment-and-arithmetic)

Answer (score 3):

If want add new row or column is used alignment (it means pandas try  matching Series index values and DataFrame columns/rows, if no match get `NaN`s for no matching values):

Your approach is good, only is necessary set same index values of `Series` for new row:

```
# Add a new row
new_movie_row = pd.Series(['Jurassic Park', 1993, 'Steven Spielberg'], index=df.columns)
df.loc[2] = new_movie_row
```

If default index values of DataFrame then default index is same, but for general data is necessary too.

```
# Add a new column
new_keyword_column = pd.Series(['Boat', 'Spider', 'Dinosaur'], index=df.index)
df['Keyword'] = new_keyword_column

print (df)
           Title  ReleaseYear          Director   Keyword
0        Titanic         1997     James Cameron      Boat
1     Spider-Man         2002         Sam Raimi    Spider
2  Jurassic Park         1993  Steven Spielberg  Dinosaur
```

But generally if need new row/column is possible use list or 1d array with same length (or scalar if need same values):

```
# Add a new row
df.loc[2] = ['Jurassic Park', 1993, 'Steven Spielberg']

# Add a new column
df['Keyword'] = ['Boat', 'Spider', 'Dinosaur']
```

---

```
# Add a new column with same values
df['same vals'] = 10
```

---

---

Why is necessary use Series and not only lists?

Only if some input data missing, then is necessary align by Series:

```
# Add a new row
new_movie_row = pd.Series(['Jurassic Park', 1993], index=['Title','ReleaseYear'])
df.loc[2] = new_movie_row
print (df)
           Title  ReleaseYear       Director
0        Titanic         1997  James Cameron
1     Spider-Man         2002      Sam Raimi
2  Jurassic Park         1993            NaN
```

Or specify columns too:

```
df.loc[2, ['Title','ReleaseYear']] = ['Jurassic Park', 1993]
```

If use only list get error:

```
df.loc[3] = ['Jurassic Park', 1993]
print (df)

>ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain why setting the `index` is required? Wouldn't it know that a column of length three would 'fit' ?

Comment: @David542 Setting index of Series solves this issue because pandas tries to align indexes

Comment: @Ch3steR I see -- it seems like using `List`s make things a bit easier than the `pd.Series` type.

Comment: @David542 - yes, if same length. If different lengths is necessary `Series`, elese error.

Comment: @David542 - added to answer.

Comment: @jezrael Fair point, if not same length using `pd.Series` with suitable index counters it.+1